# Lock Datepicker for Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm not sure this is possible, but I wanted to post on SOF anyway.

Management would like to have the Datepicker to lock on the month of what the user selects.  For example, if the user selects March...I want the back/forward arrows to not appear so that the user can not got to February or April.

Datepicker for Bootstrap:   http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: What if you use setStartDate and setEndDate and set it to first and last day of the selected month ? .. would that prevent it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your datepicker

```
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: false,
      changeYear: false,
      stepMonths: 0
    });
```